# Why does my Django form show choice not available error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, templates

I am trying to build a dynamic form in Django template.

I have two dropdown selections. When the user selects an option in the first one, the available choices in the second dropdown changes dynamically. Here is the jQuery code I use to change the choices in the second dropdown element.

```
$(document).on("change", "[id^=id_form][id$=brand]", function() {
    var $value = $(this).val();

    var $id_prefix = $(this).attr('id').slice(0, -5);
    $auto_type = $("#" + $id_prefix + "auto_type");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/europarts/filter/auto/type/with/brand/' + String($value),

        success: function(data) {
            $auto_type.html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

You can see that it fetches some HTML from a link which is basically a bunch of options which will replace the current ones. Here is the code:

```
{% for auto_type in auto_types %}
    <option value="{{ auto_type.id }}">{{ auto_type.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Here are my forms:

```
class ListForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ['ref_no']


class ProductCreateForm(forms.Form):
    brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Brand.objects.all(), initial=Brand.objects.first())
    auto_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AutoType.objects.filter(brand=Brand.objects.first()), empty_label=None)
    part_no = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()
    unit = forms.CharField(max_length=20, initial='piece(s)')
    cost_price = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    selling_price = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

I am using a dynamic formset jquery library to save multiple Products with a List.

This works fine till now!

However after I change the options like this and try to submit the form, the form page gets loaded again with the default options in the second dropdown and not the changed ones along with an error that says:

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

Here is the `request.POST` value when the form is submitted.

```
<QueryDict: {'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'form-1-description': ['lskdjf'], 'form-1-auto_type': ['3'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-0-quantity': ['1'], 'form-0-brand': ['2'], 'form-0-part_no': ['293847'], 'form-0-auto_type': ['2'], 'form-0-unit': ['piece(s)'], 'form-0-description': ['slkdfj'], 'form-1-part_no': ['928374'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['2'], 'form-1-quantity': ['1'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'ref_no': ['REF230498203948'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['WYN08Hi2YhwTSKPS8EnLaz94aOz33RVfFMjwYeHr3rMxBImxn7ggSLYHwguIbuL0'], 'form-1-brand': ['2'], 'form-1-unit': ['pieces']}>
```

You can see `'form-1-auto_type': ['3']` which was `'form-1-auto_type': ['1']` originally. The form is submitted when the original value is there, but after the dynamic change in value it shows the above error.

This error is shown for the second dropdown. How can I fix this?

Comment: do you want to fill the second option in the on select or submit

Comment: Could you show the code of your form ?

Comment: @SnakeFcz On select. My question is not clear maybe. I have managed to dynamically change the options of the second dropdown. But I cannot submit the form, it shows error when I change it dynamically.

Comment: I have answer the question can you please try it

Comment: @albar Update the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is being validated it checks whether the option exists in the choices for the field, in this case:

```
queryset=AutoType.objects.filter(brand=Brand.objects.first())
```

It works only when you select an option from the first brand.
To make it work you need to update the choices for the auto_type field before it validates the data or it might be easier not to limit the choices of auto_type to any brand and then update the select element in JavaScript when the page loads to show only the options of the first brand.

Comment: I think I'm gonna try the javascript way to update the options on load. Will accept as answer if it works. Gimme 2 mins.

Comment: I am using Django Dynamic Forms to create multiple forms. So I think using javascript would be tough. How can I update the queryset with Django? When there is a change in first dropdown I am sending request to a URL. Can I put some code in that view to change the queryset of the form field?

Comment: Never mind. I got it to work. I used javascript code: `$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#id_form-0-auto_type").html('<option value="1">Car</option>');
  });` Thanks man.

Comment: You could create a separate function that would be called when the select changes and when the page is loaded (you have most of the code inside  $(document).on("change", "[id^=id_form][id$=brand]").